# How to download pdf file in angular 2

Tags: angular2-services

This is function to download pdf file in angular 2 when I am downloading Pdf file it is corrupted file. So how do I solve this problem.
It is displaying corrupted data like this.
%PDF-1.5
%����
↵66 0 obj
<>
endobj

```
downloadFile() {
    //this.http.get('https://contactsapi.apispark.net/v1/companies/').subscribe(
    this.http.get('assets/Files/booking.pdf').subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        let parsedResponse =(response)
        var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var filename = 'booking.pdf';
        saveAs(blob, filename);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we need this package file-saver,you install like **"npm install file-saver --save"**, then you can try like this

```
 public downloadCSVFile(){
    this.downloadPdf().subscribe(
        (res) => {      
            saveAs(res,'test.pdf')
        }
    );


}

public downloadPdf(): any {
    let url='your url'
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
    return this.http.get(url,{  headers: headers,responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
        (res) => {
            return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' })
        })
}
```

Comment: I got an issue as it is giving me error saveAs is not defined. I have installed file-saver.

Comment: did you declare "declare var saveAs:any" ??

Comment: did you use webpack or systems js to build application ??

Comment: can we pass multiple files in this to download.

Comment: Yes its possible

Comment: how can u give me some idea

Comment: Don't forget npm install @types/file-saver and import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';  @Robert use FileSaver.saveAs(blobResponse, filename);

Answer (score 6):

In Angular 6, In service `downloadPdfFile.service.ts` and create the following things.

**Import Statement**

```
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Method for download pdf**

```
downloadPDF(dataObj) {

    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/pdf'
        //   'Accept': 'application/octet-stream', // for excel file
    });

    let requestOptions = { headers: headerOptions, responseType: 'blob' as 'blob' };
    // post or get depending on your requirement
    this.http.post(serviceURL, dataObj, requestOptions).pipe(map((data: any) => {

        let blob = new Blob([data], {
            type: 'application/pdf' // must match the Accept type
            // type: 'application/octet-stream' // for excel 
        });
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = 'samplePDFFile.pdf';
        link.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);

    })).subscribe((result: any) => {
    });

}
```

**component file just call the method**

```
downloadPdf()
{
     let dataObj={}
     this.downoloadPdfFileService.downloadPDF(dataObj);
   
}
```

Comment: Seems the simplest solution, no dependencies required.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a simple solution, try this:

```
<a download="b82d8486-a931-421c-b594-f4d3129746e5.pdf" target="_blank" href="/assets/files/b82d8486-a931-421c-b594-f4d3129746e5.pdf">
                Download pdf
              </a>
```