# how to read json response when expecting content type blob from server in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

How to read the json response from server when we are expecting blob response from server, there are cases on which the file is not available on the server, in that case server returns error in json format. Since, angular 2 is expecting content type as blob, it isn't able to read json returned from server.
Following is the service code:

```
public download(url: string, data: Object = null): Observable<Response> {

    let headers = new Headers();

    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers,
    });

    requestOptions.method = RequestMethod.Get;
    requestOptions.url = url;
    requestOptions.responseType = ResponseContentType.Blob;

    let request = new Request(requestOptions);
    return this._http.request(request);
}
```

Comment: can you look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45816414/7261317

Comment: I have the code to download, I want to know, how to read json in case server returns json when I am expecting content-type to be of blob type