# PDF Download functionality in Angular4 app with backend as NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, angular, pdf-generation

Anybody can suggest the way to achieve this. I have NodeJS backend API with Angular v4 as front end. I need to create pdf dynamically on the backend when user clicks on download link in frontend and pdf should be downloaded from the frontend itself.

Answer (score 0):

HI can you try this post

[Angular2 file download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45816414/7261317)

can you give file response from back-end(nodejs) then the above post will help you