# 415 Unsupported media Type when Downloading (spring boot + angular2)

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, spring-boot, download

I'm trying to implementing a download policy between my springboot app 
and my angular2 front-end.

Here's the controller method that should manage the download searching in the mongo db.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/download/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET ,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public  ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> getFile(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    FilesEntity filesEntity = filesService.getFilesById(id);
    HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    respHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", filesEntity.getNome());
    return new ResponseEntity(new FileSystemResource(FilesUtility.getFile(filesEntity.getPath())),respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Then i have to show you the method that is use on angular 2 to recover contact the backend.

```
downloadFile(link){
    let access = Cookie.get('access_token');
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-type': 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer' + access
    });

    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    //i miss some code here because i'm trying to resolve.
    this
        .http
        .get(link,options)
        .subscribe(res =>
            res.json()
        )
}
```

And lastly here's the html.component that calls  starts everything

```
<li *ngFor="let document of documents | derp"  >

    <!-- <span>{{document.id}}</span> -->
    <a class="document-name" (click)="onSelect(document)">{{document.nome}}</a>

       <a class="download" (click)="downloadFile(document.links[0].href)" >Scarica documento</a>
```

The (click) event on html calls downloadFile angular2 method passing the file id (recovered from an array inside a json response, saved in documents local variable).

I'm getting 415 http error and i can't find any good documentation related to my problem.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45816414/7261317

Comment: I will try robert, but i have fear that the back end implementaton will fight against us

Comment: you have a consumes MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, that makes the request to expect that in the request. If you remove that. it should work just fine