# Progressive web app angular download/display pdf base 64

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, pdf, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to download/display PDF document on PWA app. It works fine in desktop mode but when opened in an app on iPhone it doesn't work. I have tried below solutions:

1. iframe with source attribute = baseb4
2. object tag with data attribubte = base64
3. using anchor tag like below

   ```
   const link = document.createElement('a');
   if (link.download !== undefined) {
       const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       link.setAttribute('href', url);
       link.setAttribute('download', filename);
       link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       fileHelper.clickDownload(link);
   }
   ```

None of these techniques have worked in PWA. All of then work in desktop on browser but not in PWA. Is there a way it can be achieved?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? It should be downloading the file at least, when you click on the link.

Comment: Looks like you are creating some kind of security breach. Apple is more restrictive. Have you tried on a Macbook?

Comment: This looks like a correct approach:https://stackoverflow.com/q/45815864/5468463